# How do I make migrations for my Blazor Server app with EF Core with multiple providers?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

as the title says I am wondering how to make migrations in my Blazor Server application where I want to use EF Core with multiple providers. I want to make a CMS application, where if there is no database configured, the app shows the user a Setup page, where he needs to sekect the data provider ands then input the connection string. After that I want to apply the migrations for that specific database provider during runtime and also register the DbContext to the dependency injection during runtime.

But I am stuck at creating the migrations for all the providers.
My project structure goes as like this:

SportsOrganizer.Server (main project)

SportsOrganizer.Models (ApplicationDbContext and models)

Migrations/SportsOrganizer.SqlServer

Migrations/SportsOrganizer.MySql

Migrations/SportsOrganizer.Sqlite

Migrations/SportsOrganizer.Oracle

Migrations/SportsOrganizer.PostgreSql

I have all the nuget packages installed in the Models project. When I want to make the migrations, I set the Models project as my startup project and then I also select it in the Package manager console. I then pasted the following command:

`Add-Migration InitialCreate -Project ./Migrations/SportsOrganizer.SqlServer -Args "--provider SqlServer"` but it threw and error. I then also pasted it like this just to try if it works, but it also resulted in a different error:

`Add-Migration InitialCreate -Args "--provider SqlServer"`

So how should I go at the problem?

Also any suggestions on how to go at applying the migrations during runtime and then registering the dbcontext to dependency injection would be greately appreciated.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/providers?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

In each context ctor  `this.Database.Migrate();` . There is also `this.Database.EnsureCreated();`

Comment: @BrianParker but I have only one DbContext...

Comment: I sometimes call the migrations in program.cs and call it only if program.cs is called with a switch. This allows me to make sure the migrations are only called once and not called each time the context is created,

Comment: As per the link Create one for each provider using inheritance

Comment: @BrianParker but why would I need it. I just need to make the migrations? And I also won't have the connection strings while making the migrations. As the user would need to input them after just for migrating to the actual database

Comment: Migrations are different per database type. Connection strings can be passed in via appsettings.json

Comment: @BrianParker I know that's why I have multiple projects to store them in. Is that the reason for using multiple db context classes. But the problem is they would be the same while I generate migrations now-

Comment: Migrations are not aware of the connection string. You can change your connection string at any time. Also your connection string should be different format for each provider.. Some just look similar.

Comment: @BrianParker Ok so what do I need to do? Do you have any tutorial website?

Comment: That link I provided is specifically for multiple providers...

Comment: @BrianParker yeah I have already took a look at it, but still what bugs me is the connection string, which I don't understand why is there... Otherwise the first solution would work I guess, but still I would Maybe then need an Interface, as going through all the dbcontexts, which is the right to use wouldn't be great

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252603/discussion-between-brian-parker-and-aglasencnik).